# Incorrect password for Linux user even after changing it

Tags: linux, passwords, user

I am unable to log into a regular user account using a password, so I first change the password to something I know... 
As root,

```
passwd  theUser
```

put in the password: **thepassword**

it states it updates successfully

> passwd: all authenication tokens updated successfully

I then can

```
su - theUser
```

and Im now this user..I try

```
su - theUser
```

it asks me for the password,I put in the one I just assigned to it and it fails with

```
su: incorrect password
```

I even try to ssh into the box with that user and the password still fails.

Comment: Are you sure you're entering the same password each time?  Copy-and-paste it, don't retype it.

Comment: what means "login fails"? Please be verbose here...

Comment: There is no /bin/false in the passwd file for this user. I am cutting and pasting the password. the Logins fails with "su: incorrect password

Comment: "**su**: incorrect password" is suspicious, since **su** is not part of the normal login.

Comment: something that is interesting..  If I ssh from another box to this server and put in the correct password.. it instantly returns with "Connection closed by 22.22.22.22"...  if I try to ssh in and on purpose put the wrong password, it says "Permission denied, please try again"    so it knows the what the right password is ..it just won't let me in..

Comment: double check, what J. Bruni suggested: what is this users shell? Look it up in /etc/passwd (`sudo grep theUser /etc/passwd`)

Comment: its says:
 theuser:x:502:501::/home/theuser:/bin/bash

Comment: found this: http://www.snailbook.com/faq/libwrap-oops.auto.html

Comment: Thanks  whew! found the problem.. a lot of settings in /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac were changed.. I copied this file from a box that works and now everything is good.. Thanks all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several places to check.

- `/etc/passwd` - maybe the user has not access to a "valid shell"; if the line corresponding to this user ends with `/bin/false`, then this user does not have access to the command-line shell
- `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` - access control
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` - ssh configuration
- `/etc/security/access.conf` - security setting
- `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac` - PAM settings

Using `ssh -vv` for verbose output may help.

And a user reported that reinstalling ssh resolved his issue.

Comment: There is no /bin/false in the passwd for this user.  I am cutting and pasting the password.  the Logins fails with  "su: incorrect password"

Comment: Try a simple password, just as a test. Something like 'abc123'. Does it work? Do **not** copy/paste in this simple test.

Comment: I just tried qwer1234 as the password and still no luck :(
I mean it supposedly sets the new password  but still can't log in with it

Comment: I'd check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`... related configs: `PasswordAuthentication`, `UsePAM`, `KerberosAuthentication`, `AllowUsers`...

Comment: something that is interesting..  If I ssh from another box to this server and put in the correct password.. it instantly returns with "Connection closed by 22.22.22.22"...  if I try to ssh in and on purpose put the wrong password, it says "Permission denied, please try again"    so it knows the what the right password is ..it just won't let me in..

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I'd check also `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow`

Comment: PasswordAuthenication yes 
UsePAM yes
KerberosAuthentication is commented out
and there is not AllowUsers...

Comment: So, it seems the problem is really **not** on the "change password" step (this is happening successfully). The problem is on making the login happen. My knowledge is limited. I can only suggest you to reboot the system, if possible, try again, and see what happens.

Comment: hosts.allow and hosts.deny are fine..  I can ssh into the box as root, just not as that user.   maybe something is up with sshd_config missing the AllowUsers.. I look into that

Comment: Have you tried the ssh command with the verbose/debug mode (ssh -d3 on ssh2 or ssh -vvv with OpenSSH)... would be intresting why the connection is closed bei the foreign host.

Comment: I added  "AllowUsers theuser"    to the sshd_config, restarted the service and no change.  Also tried ssh -v, in which it state a lot of debug info BEFORE I tried putting in the password.. but as soon as I put in the password, it goes directly to "connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx"  there must be some sort of security on the box that only allows root to log in..

Comment: just checked..  /etc/nologin  does not exist..so that is not the problem

Comment: Check also `/etc/security/access.conf` - see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/openssh-root-user-account-restriction-revisited.html

Comment: I've read also an user solved this problem by purging ssh and re-installing it.

Comment: whew! found the problem.. a lot of settings in /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac were changed.. I copied this file from a box that works and now everything is good.. Thanks all!

Comment: it was hard to narrow down which line in /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac was the problem ..but i think it needed
password sufficient pam_ldap.so user_authtok

Comment: Great! You did it! I have edited my answer, so you may accept it, if you like.

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 20 in 2023.  After several reboots of the VM, the problem went away.  I am using PAM.

Answer (score 19):

Without it being apparent, [pam_faillock](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/pam_faillock.8.html) was present on the OS. I had a user account that was 'locked' which I unlocked with the following:

```
faillock --user usernameGoesHere --reset
```

Comment: All other methods failed—only this did. Saved my Arch, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from Chris, I used this command on a similar issue, with success:

```
faillog --user usernameGoesHere --reset
```

Comment: This is basically a copy of Chris' answer, but with even less explanation about the command. You probably had a good intention, but re-posting it isn't very helpful. If his answer worked for you, you should simply upvote his answer. =)

Comment: I would very much like to, but I am 14 points from having access to upvoting and 49 points from commenting his post.
And yes my intention was good, so if someone could add my 2 cents to Chris' answer I wouldn't mind.
I would hate if someone was in my situation, and didn't manage to discover faillog instead of faillock :)